# Kibana Vega-Lite use aggregates as data

Tags: kibana, vega-lite

I am new with Vega-Lite in Kibana. I am trying to produce a bar chart in Kibana using Vega.
I use Vega because I have to use nested fields, and it seems there are not other options.
I don't want to plot a time series, I want to directly plot aggregates.
This is my script:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "title": "Event counts from all indexes",
  data: {
    name: "aggregations"
    url: {
      %context%: true
      %timefield%: timestamp
      index: search-sonarqube-telemetry-2021-merged
      body: {
        "aggs": {
          "languages": {
            "terms": { "field": "plugins.name.keyword"}  
          }
        }
        size: 0
      }
    }
    format: {property: "aggregations.languages.buckets" }
  }
 
 
  mark: bar

  encoding: {
    y: {
      field: "buckets.key"
      type: nominal
      axis: { title: null }
    }
    x: {
      field: "buckets.doc_count"
      type: quantitative
      axis: { title: "Document count" }
    }
    
  }
  
  transform: [
    {"filter":
      {"field": "doc_count", "range": [0,100000]}
    }
  ]  
}
```

Everything is empty.
If I try to debug, I see the source_0, with the correct data I would like to plot, but not the data_0.

I also get the warnings:
Infinite extent for field "buckets.doc_count_start": [Infinity, -Infinity]
Infinite extent for field "buckets.doc_count_end": [Infinity, -Infinity]

What is wrong in my script?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I defined the property as aggregations.languages.buckets, but the I was defined the fields as buckets.key and buckets.doc_count in the encoding.
It was enough to replace key and doc_count to buckets.key and buckets.doc_count and it worked.
Actually it was not finding the fields because inside aggregations.languages.buckets we don't have a repetition of buckets.